# How to create a performance system that count tags across a large dynamic dataset

Tags: php, mongodb, design-patterns, database-design, architecture

**Overview**

I have an `iOS` app where people can search by `tags` some of the tags will be pre-defined and some will be user defined.

As the user write the `tags` that he/she wants to search for I would like to display a row that shows the number of results available with those `tags` (See example search picture).

**Note:** `#Exercise` or `#Routine`  are parent `tag` meaning that the person is always going to use one of those first.

I am using `PHP` and `MongoDB` server side.
I though of creating a file with the tags count every hour so that all clients can fetch it and minimize resource consumption.

Given that the manipulated information are `tags` which are user controlled, the list will expand considerably over time.

**The challenge**

- I am puzzled on whats the best approach when taking into account
  performance & overhead for creating, manipulating & storing such
  list.

**My first idea** was to create a `2d array` (see pic) that will store all my values. This then will be transformed into a JSON so that it can stored into MongoDB.

But this approach will make me to fetch all tags and load them in memory to do any +1 or -1. Thus, I do not think it might be the best.

All the manipulation would take place on insert,update and delete of each element. Thus there will be a considerable `RAM` overhead.

**My second idea** was to create a `document` where I store all my used `tags` and make the count queries every hour to produce the list used by the clients.

This would mean on every delete, update and insert check that the tag exist on this `document` and create or delete or do nothing depending on condition.

Every hour, fetch all tags, produce an array with all tags combinations. Query the DB against all  tags combinations and count the number of results returned and create the file.

This approach, I think, could be the better one given that I use `MongoDB` and not `MySQL`. But I am still unsure of its performance.

Have anyone made a similar system and could advice on a better approach?

**Example Picture of the search**

[image]

**2d Array**

[image]

Comment: I never worked with MongoDB or any other NoSQL database. But, anyway, try an memcached alternative is a good solution no? Let me know more about your architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most important things to consider when using mongodb is that you must think in terms of your application's access patterns when deciding on database design. We will try to solve your problem by using an example and see how it works.

Let's consider that you have the following documents in your collection and let us see below how to make this simple data format work wonders:

```
> db.performant.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("522bf7166094a4e72db22827"), "name" : "abc", "tags" : [  "chest",  "bicep",  "tricep" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("522bf7406094a4e72db22828"), "name" : "def", "tags" : [  "routine",  "trufala",  "tricep" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("522bf75f6094a4e72db22829"), "name" : "xyz", "tags" : [  "routine",  "myTag",  "tricep",  "myTag2" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("522bf7876094a4e72db2282a"), "name" : "mno", "tags" : [  "exercise",  "myTag",  "tricep",  "myTag2",  "biceps" ] }
```

First and foremost you **absolutely must** create an index on tags. (you can create a compound index if desire)

```
> db.performant.ensureIndex({tags:1})
> db.performant.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.performant",
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "tags" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.performant",
            "name" : "tags_1"
    }
]
```

To query the tags data from the above collection, one would normally use db.performant.find({tags:{$in:["bicep"]}}), but this is **not a good idea**. Let me show you why:

```
> db.performant.find({tags:{$in:["bicep","chest","trufala"]}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1 multi",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 3,
    "nscanned" : 5,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 5,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "tags" : [
                    [
                            "bicep",
                            "bicep"
                    ],
                    [
                            "chest",
                            "chest"
                    ],
                    [
                            "trufala",
                            "trufala"
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "none-6674b8f4f2:27017"
}
```

As you might have already noticed, this query is performing an entire collection scan. This may make you wonder, why the hack we added that index, if its not used and I am wondering that too. But unfortunately, its an issue that is yet to be resolved by mongoDB (at least in my knowledge)

Fortunately though, we can get around this problem and still use the index we created on tags collection. Here is how:

```
> db.performant.find({$or:[{tags:"bicep"},{tags:"chest"},{tags:"trufala"}]}).explain()
{
    "clauses" : [
            {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "n" : 1,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
                    "nscanned" : 1,
                    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
                    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nYields" : 0,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "millis" : 10,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                            "tags" : [
                                    [
                                            "bicep",
                                            "bicep"
                                    ]
                            ]
                    }
            },
            {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
                    "nscanned" : 1,
                    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
                    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nYields" : 0,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "millis" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                            "tags" : [
                                    [
                                            "chest",
                                            "chest"
                                    ]
                            ]
                    }
            },
            {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "n" : 1,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
                    "nscanned" : 1,
                    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
                    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nYields" : 0,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "millis" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                            "tags" : [
                                    [
                                            "trufala",
                                            "trufala"
                                    ]
                            ]
                    }
            }
    ],
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 3,
    "nscanned" : 3,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
    "millis" : 10,
    "server" : "none-6674b8f4f2:27017"
}
```

As you can see, n is very very close to nscanned. There are three records scanned 1 each corresponding to "bicep","chest","trufala". Since "bicep" and "chest" belong to the same document, only 1 result is returned corresponding to it. In general, both count() and find() will do limited scans and will be very efficient. Also, you never have to serve user with stale data. You can also completely avoid running any sorts of batch jobs whatsoever!!!

So, by using this approach we can derive the following **conclusion**: If you search by n tags, and each tag is present m times, then total documents scanned will be n * m. Now considering you have huge number of tags and huge number of documents, and you scan by a few tags (which in turn correspond to few documents - although not 1:1), the results will always be super fast, since 1 document scan occurs per tag and document combination.

**Note:** The index can never be covered with this approach, since there is an index on array i.e. "isMultiKey" : true. You can read more on covered indexes [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries)

**Limitations:** Every approach has limitations, and this one has too!!
Sorting on results will yield an extremely poor performance as it will scan the entire collection the number of times equal to the tags passed to this query plus it scans additional records corresponding to each argument of $or.

```
> db.performant.find({$or:[{tags:"bicep"},{tags:"chest"},{tags:"trufala"}]}).sort({tags:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 15,
    "nscanned" : 15,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 15,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 15,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "tags" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "none-6674b8f4f2:27017"
}
```

In this case, it scans 15 times which is equal to 3 full collection scans of 4 records each plus 3 records scanned by each parameter for $or

**Final verdict:** Use this approach for very efficient results if you are ok with unsorted results or are willing to make extra effort at your front end to sort them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is long, I'm going to list some assumptions I've made after reading over the question a few times:

1. People can enter in *n* number of tags to search by.
2. Tags are pre-defined or user defined.
3. Tags will grow considerably over time.
4. We want the count of total documents for a given set of tags. If #tag1 has 10 and #tag2 has 13, then we have roughly 23 documents (considering some might have both tags).

I have a few recommendations for an approach:

1. You've already started to think this way, but plan to separate reads from writes. If someone tags a document with **#chest**, go ahead and write that immediately, but be ok with not having that information available on all reads yet. (This goes back to your job that runs every hour.)
2. You can give the user that tagged a document immediate feedback. I've read that YouTube does this. You like something on YouTube and it increments the number immediately, even though the write hasn't committed. The idea is that you give the user *something* immediately - even if it isn't completely accurate.
3. Building on (2), consider that the numbers just need to be "good enough". Searching for **#chest** and **#routine** ... let's say that returns **100** results. Feel free to display 98 or 99 instead. It's in the ballpark. In other words, it's ok to not account for +1 and -1 right away as long as the user can get a feel for how many results there are.
4. Consider running a job that moves the data out of Mongo. You can have Mongo run a map/reduce query that outputs to a collection in Mongo. Then you can put this in something like Redis to serve data. Or I suppose you could keep it in Mongo.
5. I'm not sure I would create all possible combinations. That is going to grow out of control *very* fast - especially if people can create their own tags. Instead, just create a simple data structure that has the search term with the count. ["#chest", 100], ["#routine", 543], ["#triceps", 12], ...
6. The point can be made that if a document has multiple tags, we'll be counting it twice. That's true, but I would argue for simplicity to leave that alone. If you're willing to sacrifice a little precision with the counts, then your code will be easier to maintain and perform well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Addressing point 5, most tags will have more than 1 tag and I guess if you search for `#routine #chest #bicep` you only want routines with those muscle groups and the approximate count of that criteria. I understand that problably counting all possible combinations could result in a crazy list, but maybe there is a way to do that?.... otherwise i would have to fall back into maybe only showing a count for `system tags`

Answer (score 0):

**Update: rewriting this concept to avoid confusion over MySQL examples**

As stated in the original answer, I am MongoDB ignorant. So, I will simply explain the concept.

There may still be a way to have accurate counts with decent performance. This is based on the assumption that you want the intersection of the list of tags (all documents that contain all of the requested tags).

1) Create a new collection (tags_query_cache) that contains 3 fields:

- tags_key   : primary key - a string of all of the tags in the query
- tags_count : the number of documents that contain all of the tags in the tags_list
- tags_list  : an array of tags - all of the tags in tags_key (should be an index on tags)

2) When updating | adding | deleting a document in your original collection:

- identify all of the tags in the document that have changed (added or deleted)
- delete all documents in the tags_query_cache collection that contain the changed tags that were identified

3) When a query (by tags) is performed against your original collection:

- create the tags_key by imploding (PHP implode function) a sorted, lowercase, list of tags being queried
- find the document in the tags_query_cache that has tags_key = the imploded list of tags
- if the document is found, tags_count contains your counts
- if the document is not found, query the original collection to get the number of documents (see @Nilesh Rajani's answer)
- add a new document to the tags_query_cache collection for this set of tags with the count just retrieved

The advantage to this approach:

- you always have current document counts and are able to retrieve them from the tags_query_cache with a single full key match (if the tags_query_cache document exists)
- you only build tags_query_cache documents for relevant combinations of tags (i.e. you don't have to anticipate every possible combination)
- the processing requirements to build tags_query_cache is spread over multiple user inquiries.

There are other paths that can be taken depending on the anticipated volume of updates to your original collection vs. the anticipated volume of queries vs. the accuracy of the count of documents that is desired. If you don't have to have counts that are 100% accurate or if the volume of updates is expected to be significant compared to the volume of queries by tag (not likely), you could do something like:

- add a last_updated date/time field to the tags_query_cache collection
- don't delete from tags_query_cache every time a document in your original collection has a change to it's tags
- when retrieving from the tags_query_collection, if the last_updated date/time is older than your desired interval, recalculate the number of documents in your original collection that contain the desired tags and update the tags_query_cache document.

It should also be noted that the tags_query_cache doesn't HAVE to reside in MongoDB on disk somewhere. A memory cache that is sharable across all running processes could be used to improve performance. The downside is that when the machine goes down, you lose your cached results.

Good luck. Hope this is clearer than the original.

Comment: Mongodb is not a relational database. Following [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#what-kind-of-database-is-mongodb) should be helpful.

Comment: @Nilesh Rajani - shame for the down vote. While mongoDB is not a relational DB, it does allow for relationships (you have demonstrated that). My use of MySQL was an attempt to explain a CONCEPT using what I know. A concept that can be implemented with decent performance (as shown in your answer). Take your counts and put it in a table keyed by the implosion of all of the tags, and you have my proposed solution. The fact that I used MySQL as a means of explaining the concept makes the concept no less legitimate. Don't throw out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: I did not down vote and you can confirm that by viewing my rep changes!!

Comment: @Nilesh Rajani - sorry. my bad. obviously bad assumption on my part.

Comment: no probs :)
I can understand the reaction after the effort you have put!